# Prove that sequence $a_n/n$ is convergent for $a_n = 1+\frac15+\frac19... + \frac1{4n-3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Show that the sequence $\langle a_n\rangle$ where

$a_n = 1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}... + \frac{1}{4n-3}$

does not converge, whereas $\langle b_n\rangle$ defined by $b_n = \frac{1}{n}  a_n$ converges to 0.

My Approach: I was able to prove that $\langle a_n\rangle$ does not converge by showing that it is not a Cauchy sequence but not able to prove that $\langle b_n\rangle$ is converging sequence. Is there a theorem related to this?.

Answer (score 1):

I completely misread the question at first. Let's try again. We know that for $k\geq1$, we have $4k-3\geq k$, and hence 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k-3}\leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.
$$
The sum on the right gives the harmonic numbers, $H_n$, which are approximated asymptotically by $\ln(n)$ (given by a Riemann approximation of $\int_1^n\frac{1}{x}dx$). Thus since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0,$$
we may apply the squeeze theorem to 
$$0\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k-3}\leq \frac{C+\ln(n)}{n}$$
(where $C$ is an arbitrarily large, fixed constant to make the inequality hold). Thus we have $b_n\to0$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the catch on the indices. The sum is bounded below by $1$ though, so it surely does not converge to $0$.

Comment: You changed an $n$ that shouldn't have been changed with the edit.  $b_n=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\color{red}{n}(4k-3)}\right)$.  It is not as immediately obvious of a problem as you are making it out to be.

Comment: @JMoravitz completely misread the question at first. Sorry about that, thank you for the catches

Comment: Is there any way to prove the sequence of $b_n$ as a Cauchy sequence ?.

Comment: @DoraemonJr Yes, because every convergent series is Cauchy

Answer (score 1):

With [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), $b_{n}=n$ is strictly monotone and divergent sequence and 
$${\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }{\frac {a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{b_{n+1}-b_{n}}} } ={\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty }\dfrac{1}{4n+1}}=0$$
Then, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{n}=0$ as well.

Comment: Why are you referring to "$b_n=n$"?  This doesn't seem to be related to the $b_n$ defined in the problem above.

Comment: @JMoravitz $b_n$ refer to sequence in wiki link!

Comment: Change the name to something else then.  $b_n$ is already in use in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let, 
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k$$
$$b_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\theta_k$$
In the first sequence,
$$\alpha_k=\frac{1}{4k-3}$$
$$\theta_k=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{4k-3}$$
$$\theta_k=\frac{\alpha_k}{n}$$
Now taking derivative,
$$\frac{d}{dk}[\theta_k]=\frac{-4}{n(4k-3)^2}$$
The derivative of $\theta_k$ is therefore negative for all $k$ such that $k\not= \frac{3}{4}$ is negative and for all $n$

Hence the $\theta_k$ is monotone decreasing in $k\gt 1$

Hence we can apply the integral test on $b_n$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_1^{n}\frac{1}{4x-3} dx $$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\ln (4n-3)}{4n}-0$$
Applying L'Hospital rule,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{4}{4n-3}}{4}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{4n-3}$$
$$0$$

The integral is finite, hence the sum is convergent.

Comment: A few final fixes that I did (*e.g. upper limits of summations*).  Most of our conversation can now be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

$$1+1/5+1/9+...\geq 1/2+1/6+1/10+...=$$ $$=(1/2)(1+1/3+1/5+...)\geq (1/2)(1/2+1/4+1/6+...)=$$ $$=(1/4)(1+1/2+1/3+...).$$ Let $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^n1/j.$ We have  $$s_2=3/2.$$ $$s_4=s_2+(1/3+1/4)>s_2+2(1/4)=2.$$ $$s_8=s_4+(1/5+...+1/8)>s_4+4(1/8)>2+1/2=5/2.$$ $$s_{16}=s_8+(1/9+...+1/16)>s_8+8(1/16)>5/2+1/2=3.$$ Et cetera.

Comment: This only succeeds in showing the first part of the problem, that $a_n$ is increasing and unbounded, rehashing a proof of the divergence of the harmonic series which could just as easily been cited, linked to elsewhere or referred to in a book (*everyone should have seen it by the time they've been asked this question*).  The challenging part of the question has to do with the nature of the convergence of $b_n$ which you have not yet touched upon.